# Setting output of spatial ETL tool in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, data-interoperability, spatial-etl

I am using the data interoperability extension and building spatial ETL tools, but I can't seem to specify the output location of the ETL tool so it's impossible to use this dynamically.

Has anyone figured out how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

**Data Interoperability Extension 10 Service Pack 1**- fixes this issue

http://resources.arcgis.com/content/patches-and-service-packs?fa=viewPatch&PID=83&MetaID=1721

```
NIM058671 - Cannot specify Output Dataset for the Quick Export tool when it is in a model.
NIM058766 - Cannot specify Input Dataset for the Quick Import tool when it is in a model.
NIM058645 - Data Interoperability is unable to export to the Adobe Geospatial PDF file format.
NIM058646 - FME Workbench is missing some transformers.
NIM057999 - Optional Published Parameters for Spatial ETL Tools do not behave like “optional” parameters.
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating the Spatial ETL Tool in Workbench make sure that the Destination is Purple in colour, this will mean it is set to publish the output location.

!shows the Toolbox view of the output location[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYtew.png)

Once done then in the model that calls the Spatial ETL Tool you can identify the output location as a parameter and then it is able to be set as any model parameter.

!Model Window showing Parameter[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYtew.png)

Comment: Turns out that the issue is not that the output is not available to model builder, but it is not available as a variable in model builder... so I wrote a python script to wrap around the ETL script so that I can define the output location in another model.. (ouch)